# How to assign variable to method in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I am a beginner and just recetly started learning c#.
So I have a task:
*Prepare a program for typing lines with integers on the keyboard to*
display on the screen how
many lines each contains, their sum and product, and their maximum, minimum and average
values. Numbers in rows are separated by spaces and tabs.

What I don't understand is how to work with that method in Main. Like do I need to assigned it to variable to be able to count sum, max, min and how to do that?

Numbers method is given. The code I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        string x;
        Console.WriteLine("Input numbers in each line (seperate by spaces):");
        Console.WriteLine("End - enter");

        while ((x = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
        {
            Numbers(x);
            
        }
        
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    static int[] Numbers(string e, params char[] sk)
    {
        string[] zod = e.Split(sk, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int[] num = new int[zod.Length];
        int n = 0;
        foreach (string t in zod)
            if (int.TryParse(t, out num[n]))
                n++;
        if (n > 0)
            Array.Resize(ref num, n);
        else num = null;
        return num;
    }`
```

Comment: `int[] numbers = Numbers(x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply modify :

```
while ((x = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
{
   //option 1
   var nums = Numbers(x);   
   //option 2
   int[] nums = Numbers(x);
   
}
```